# pyspark drop and merge rows

Tags: parsing, pyspark

I am trying to parse some file and put data to the table:

```
File = "somehtml.file"  
Data = spark.read.text(File)

df_file = Data.select(regexp_extract("col1", '(.*?)', 0).alias("somedata"), \
                regexp_extract("col1", '(.*?)', 0).alias("somedata2"))
```

after that I have not correct result:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|            somedata|           somedata2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|http://sweersdsh.ru....|                    |
|                    |helo my name lololol...|
|                    |                    |
|                    |                    |
|http://qweuiewjk.ru....|                    |
|                    |helo my name alallal...|
```

and I needed this one:

`+--------------------+--------------------+
|            somedata|           somedata2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|http://sweersdsh.ru....|helo my name lololol...|
|http://qweuiewjk.ru....|helo my name alallal...|`

this out any `''` , please help me

Comment: Did you tried [trim](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.trim) column? `Data.select(trim(regexp_extract("col1", '(.*?)', 0).alias("somedata")), trim(regexp_extract("col1", '(.*?)', 0).alias("somedata2")))`

Comment: Yes, col1 looks like html page with tags in each rows, I try to parse data from some tags and add to the table. But if Regex does’t find needed tag he return to the table ‘’

Comment: I have like this:
`[Row(somedata='http://sweersdsh.ru', somedata2=''),
 Row(somedata='', somedata2='helo my name lololol'),`
and I need:
`[Row(somedata='http://sweersdsh.ru', somedata2='helo my name lololol')`

Comment: Note that the `df` tag is for the Unix command by that name and has nothing to do with dataframes.